# What was the last mathematical paper published in Latin?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

From an [answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59954/59966#59966) I learned that Peano [published in Latin](http://ia600200.us.archive.org/3/items/arithmeticespri00peangoog/arithmeticespri00peangoog.pdf) as long as 1889.

> What was the last mathematical paper/book of recognized importance published in Latin?

Comment: My understanding is that the last paper/book of widely recognized importance in *any* field was Peano's work.  I don't recall where I read that though.  I think that refers to the 1889 work, although later Peano would rework his "Formulario" in his Latin sine flexione.  Though, of course, you don't find "research-level" articles in Latin, you can still find texts like this in Latin: http://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica

Comment: With Peano this may have been something of an affectation.  Gauss' _Disquisitiones Arithmeticae_ was in Latin and was published in or about 1800.  It's probably not the last one.  But I wouldn't be surprised if it's the last one that was as important as it was.

Comment: Tangential, but this history of Dirichlet highlights his hurdles with working in Latin. http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/tschinkel/gauss-dirichlet/elstrodt-new.pdf

Comment: Possibly not quite comparable with *Disquisitiones*, but still very important, is Jacobi's 1829 *Fundamenta Nova Theoriae Functionum Ellipticarum*.

Comment: There's an essay by Riemann from 1861: see http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Paris/

Comment: I recall having read a quote in Latin concerning the equation $d^2 = 0$, arising in (co)homology; I believe it was in the preface of some Oxford or Cambridge Univ. Press work of/on Atiyah or one of his colleagues. It might not be what you're looking for, but it does indicate that some universities have written about maths in Latin as a form of "invention of tradition".

Comment: Are there any mathematicians in the Vatican?

Comment: Gerben: The quote is of Henri Cartan. It's at the very beginning of Gelfand & Manin's *Methods of Homological Algebra*. The quote comes from Cartan's acceptance speech when he received a Doctor Honoris Causa title in 1980. I wonder to what extent exactly this is a joke, akin to http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~dehornoy/Clips/PatrickSpeech.mpg

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Zentralblatt lets you search by language of paper where I discovered this recent example.

> **Schechtman, Vadim**
>   *New definition of a vertex algebroid. (Definitio nova algebroidis verticiani.)* (Latin)
>   A Bernstein, Joseph (ed.) et al., Studies in Lie theory. Dedicated to A. Joseph on his sixtieth birthday. 
>   Basel: Birkhäuser. Progress in Mathematics 243, 443-494 (2006).

In the preface, the editors note that Schechtman's paper is "linguistically refreshing"!

Comment: Here's the link: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-8176-4478-4_18

Comment: *In the preface, the editors note that Schechtman's paper is "linguistically refreshing"!* – They should have said *linguistically reviving …*