# What is the origin of the prefix logic notation used in WFF 'N PROOF?

Tags: logic, notation, math-history, education

The classic "modern logic" game of [WFF 'N PROOF](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5663/wff-n-proof) uses a set of symbols to represent logical relations that I've seen used nowhere else: $C$ for *then*; $A$ for *or*; $K$ for *and*; $E$ for *if and only if*; and $N$ for *not*. These are used in prefix notation so that, for example $$CNpq$$ means $$\neg p\Rightarrow q,$$ and $$EpAqNr$$ means $$p\Leftrightarrow \left({q\vee\neg r}\right).$$

What is the [origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59954/12400) of these symbols and have they been used widely or elsewhere? Are they still in use?

Comment: Your [link](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5663/wff-n-proof) contains a recent [forum thread](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/699725/why-use-arbitrary-letters-instead-of-familiar-logi) debating that very question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation#Polish_notation_for_logic). For example, $K$ stands for *koniunkcja*, from the same root as "conjunction".

Comment: It was called "Polish notation" because of people who could not remember the name Łukasiewicz.

Comment: [Some examples](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/Home-page.htm) of the use of this notation.

Answer (score 4):

The "Polish" notation was introduced by my academic grandfather, Jan Łukasiewicz (1878-1956).

A famous joint paper with Tarski,
"Untersuchungen über den Aussagenkalkül," (1930) 
 contains the phrase
"Łukasiewicz employs the formulas *Cpq* and *Np*."
A footnote indicates that Łukasiewicz used the notation in a paper from 1929 and in 
his famous text *Elementy logiki matematycznej* (1929) which contains 
the contents of a course given
"in the autumn trimester of the academic year 1928/9". 
In a paper by Łukasiewicz from 1931 a footnote reports that 
"I came upon the idea of a parenthesis-free notation in 1924."
Thus 1924 seems to be the most likely date of the creation 
of Łukasiewicz's parenthese free notation.

The notation has been, and continues to be, widely used in the study of propositional calculi.

Comment: This answer deserves to get accepted.  By "academic grandfather" do you mean that your thesis adviser had  Łukasiewicz as his/her thesis adviser (or someone further down the line)?  Also, and I guess this wanders a bit... I've read that C. A. Meredith developed condensed detachment building on Łukasiewicz's work.  I'd like to know how he did this, but I don't have access to his work.  Did Meredith basically get the idea or build on the way in Łukasiewicz notated his proofs?

Comment: On the work of C. A. Meredith, see "In memoriam: Carew Arthur Meredith (1904--1976)" _Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic_, Volume 18, Number 4 (1977), 513-516, by his cousin David Meredith. [Google](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093888116.)

Comment: The paper is on line: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093888116.  Yes, my advisor, Boleslaw Sobocinski was a PhD student of Łukasiewicz.